# Prove that the time complexity of a function is O(n^3)

Tags: time-complexity, runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

```
    public void function2(long input) {
    long s = 0;

    for (long i = 1; i < input * input; i++){
        for(long j = 1; j < i * i; j++){
            s++;
        }
    }
}
```

l'm pretty certain that the time complexity of this function is n^3, however if someone could provide a line by line explanation of this, that would be great.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Please, bring something to the question. We help, but we do not do homeworks :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to define what `n` is if you write something like `O(n^3)`, otherwise it doesn't make any sense. Let's say `n` is the value (as opposed to e.g. the bit-length) of `input`, so `n = input`.

The outer loop has `k` iterations, where `k = n^2`. The inner loop has `1^2`, `2^2`, `3^2`, ... up to `k^2` iterations, so summing up everything you get `O(k^3)` iterations (since the sum of the `p`-th powers of the first `m` integers is always `O(m^(p+1))`).

Hence the overall time complexity is `O(n^6)`.